# copy_exec command not found when executing update-initramfs

Tags: initramfs

I'm currently trying to include cryptsetup into my initramfs so i can boot after having encrypted the root partition.

I created a hook-script in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/my_hook`

With the following content

```
copy_exec /sbin/cryptsetup /sbin
```

But everytime i try to execute (in chroot)

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

It fails with:

```
root@ubuntu update-initramfs -u -k all
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/my_hook 
:1 /usr/share/initramfs- tools/hooks/my_hook copy_exec: not found

E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/my_hook failed with return 127
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to rewrite `my_hook` to fit the standard calling convention AND to include the **hook-functions** (this is the important part)

```
#!/bin/sh -e

PREREQ=""

#Output prequisites
prereqs()
{
    echo "$PREREQ"
}

case $1 in prereqs)
    preqres
    exit 0;;
esac

. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions # this is crucial
```